# TextEdit keeps getting stuck

Tags: high-sierra, textedit

TextEdit keeps getting stuck in the middle of files stopping me from being able to scroll down any further. I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 - I don't remember ever having these issues on Sierra 10.12.

The only fixes I've found for this so far are:

- adding a new line and then deleting it
- closing textedit and re-opening (but this doesn't always fix it)

Is there a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: How large was your file?  I'm running High Sierra but I haven't encountered this problem.

Comment: The file I'm working on at the moment is a plain text file .txt and it's only 112 KB - TextEdit's plain text file screen is a bit different than their "rich" text gui - not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

Comment: I've tried reproducing your problem using plain text files of sizes up to 2 MB but TextEdit scrolls smoothly throughout the file.  I assume you have TextEdit 1.13 which comes with High Sierra.  Do your file names have a unique extension?

Comment: @jhm Yeah, I'm on 1.13 (332) - file names are all .txt - nothing special. Chinese character files tho - if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user3306356 Maybe try copying TextEdit from Sierra over. It should still work, although I have not tested.

Comment: @user3306356 Can you test the same thing except with only Roman/Latin characters? (Non Chinese characters). But at the same length.

Comment: @Josh I can try, but the thing is that it doesn't systematically "break" or "stick", making the bug kind of hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar difficulties in the past. I have found a work around that may solve or assist you in your issue. I found that if I first extend the window vertically so the text all fits into it, therefore eliminating the need to scroll, it works correctly. Unfortunately, this won't work for long documents where it can not fit on the screen entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use Page-Up and Page-Down such as, function-arrow keys, to see entire document and edit the document.  Apple should be ashamed of this bug.

Comment: Page-up & page-down function keys work but they sink below where I can scroll. The only method I've found that works is creating newlines and then deleting them.